# How to control more than one image position with Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am making a game with Kivy where you can move a character around the screen.  Earlier, I had it working where when you move the character right, the background image would scroll to the left, and same with the right.  Recently, what I tried to do was add the background image to a widget along with another image, with the intention that i could control multiple image locations with 'widget.pos', but as soon as I did this, not only does the second image (hero2) not scroll right or left but neither does the background image.  I am wondering what I did wrong in my code here.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FallOutTransition


gamelayout = FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))


class Game(Screen):
    pass    


class IconButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class Bg(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Bg, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.allow_stretch = True
        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.size = (1440, 1440)

class MoveableImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
        self.size_hint = (.11, .11)
        self.y = (Window.height/2.1)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()



    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x < (Window.width * .25):
                self.app.test.x += 4
            else:
                self.x -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.x > (Window.width * .70):
                self.app.test.x -= 4
            else:
                self.x += 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.20
            if self.y < (Window.height * .25):
                self.app.test.y += 4
            else:
                self.y -= 6
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/back.zip'
            self.anim_delay=.1
            if self.y > (Window.height * .70):
                self.app.test.y -= 4
            else:
                self.y += 6
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'right':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/right1.png'
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.source ='selectionscreen/back2.png'
        else:
            return False
        return True



class gameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm 
        sm = ScreenManager()
        game = Game(name='game')
        sm.add_widget(game)
        hero = MoveableImage(source='selectionscreen/jeezyright1.png', pos=(75, 40))
        self.hero2 = Image(source='selectionscreen/hero2.zip', pos=(100, 200))
        self.background=Bg(source='selectionscreen/background9.png')
        self.test=Bg()
        self.test.add_widget(self.background)
        self.test.add_widget(self.hero2)
        gamelayout.add_widget(self.test)
        gamelayout.add_widget(hero)
        game.add_widget(gamelayout)
        return sm






if __name__ == '__main__':
    gameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem here is that you are using a FLoatLayout. When you move a normal layout (such as a FloatLayout), it does not automatically change the children's co-ordinates. If you want that behavior, try using a RelativeLayout.

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html

Peace out